# SSL Certs for Plex Media Server using Letstencrypt

Tags: ssl, certbot, plex

I need a little direction here. I want to get https with my hostname that I generated at No-IP working with my Plex Media Server. I can connect through my hostname to my plex media server just fine I just want letsencrypt to generate secure SSL certs for it.

I run the following command:

```
sudo su -
./certbot-auto  --webroot "/var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support" -d example.com
```

and it return the following error:

```
letsencrypt: error: unrecognized arguments: /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support
```

If I run the following command:

```
sudo su -
./certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com
```

It return the following error:

Failed authorization procedure. example.com (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Incorrect validation certificate for TLS-SNI-01 challenge. Requested e1b6ab6aa7251a908a0f2fc1dd6a3597.beae34c6504c7db8412d92c3f1885e08.acme.invalid from 1.2.3.4:443. Received certificate containing '*.0beedbf17c2042c089ef5e20952e62c8.plex.direct'

I really don't even know if that is the right webroot or not. I'm at a complete lose as to where to go from here. This is the last step in my puzzle and any direction would be helpful.

**Note:** This is running on a Rasberry pi 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you already have plex setup so I will skip that part, if not look at this link: [wesleysinstructions.weebly.com](http://wesleysinstructions.weebly.com/)

1. Go to No-IP (or any other service you want to use for a hostname) and setup a hostname

   - Login To the dashboard.
   - On the side bar click "Dynamic DNS"
   - Select "Hostnames"
   - On that page click the button "Add Hostname"
     ​   - Fill that out and you now have a hostname (Note: This takes about 5 minutes to become active)
2. Install the Dynamic DNS client to link your plex ip address (that is always changing) to your hostname on No-Ip.com

   - Note: They have instructions on their website on how to do this
3. On your router port forward 443/80 to where you're hosting plex

- Visit portforward.com for instructions regarding your exact router

4. SSH into your plex server
5. Install "certbot" by LetsEncrypt

```
mkdir ~/certs
cd ~/certs
wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
sudo chmod a+x certbot-auto
sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d <hostname>
```

- NOTE: This will attempt to verify the host over 443.
- If everything goes well you should get a message that looks something like this:

```
Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at
/etc/letsencrypt/live/<hostname>/fullchain.pem. Your cert
will expire on..
```

6. Setup a Reverse Nginx proxy to serve your cert.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx -y
sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse
```

The "reverse" file is setup something like the following:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  <hostname>;
    rewrite https://$host$request_uri? permanent;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<hostname>/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<hostname>/privkey.pem;
    #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #index index.html index.htm;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:32400;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

- Note: This assumes you have the default plex setup where it is using port 32400.

Finish the setup

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reverse
sudo nginx -t
sudo service nginx restart
```

Hopefully I didn't type anything wrong. If I did at least this is the setup process you will need to go through.

Comment: Is there a reason for the -1?

Comment: I suppose they down-voted your answer because it does not tell what you did but points to an external URL that could change or disappear. That's why it's preferred to copy the relevant part here.

Comment: Hum good point. I'll get that compiled and copy some of those here.